# print number in some digits in python

Tags: python

Is there a way for python to print number with digits like this

```
no = ["1", "2", "3", "99", "999"]

print no
```

and it print like this

```
001, 002, 003, 099, 999
```

actually for print textfile names with digit number

```
openFile = 'D:/Workspace/python.txt'
savePlace = 'D:/Workspace/python{}.txt'

with open(openFile, 'rb') as inf:
    for index, line in enumerate(inf,start=0):
        with open(savePlace.format(index) ,'w') as outf:
        ....
```

output in D:/Workspace

```
python001.txt
python002.txt
python003.txt
python099.txt
python999.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the other answers are correct and you can use `zfill`, you can also achieve the same result by changing your format string

```
savePlace = 'D:/Workspace/python{}.txt'
```

to

```
savePlace = 'D:/Workspace/python{0:03d}.txt'
```

and leaving the rest of your code as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the easiest way would be [zfill(3)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.zfill). For your case you will do something like this:

```
no = ["1", "2", "3", "99", "999"]
out = [i.zfill(3) for i in no]
```

Then you can modify it in whatever way to do your thing with files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting).

[str.zfill()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) also can do. But `str.format()` is more powerful method.

```
>>> ["{:0>3}".format(x) for x in no]
['001', '002', '003', '099', '999']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[x.zfill(3) for x in no]
```

You can use this.